# Apply colored circle on top of the clicked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that when loaded displays this:

[image]

The HTML for this is as follows (the below is built within a foreach statement in the view as I'm using MVC 5)

```
<div class="boxTop"></div>
  <div id="panel1" class="box">
    <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0" style="margin-left:-8%">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <img data-name="blackcherry" alt="cherries.png" data-id="1" src="/Content/Images/FlavourLab/cherries.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
         <img data-name="coconut" alt="coconut" data-id="2" src="/Content/Images/FlavourLab/coconut.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0" style="margin-left:-8%">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
         <img data-name="mango" alt="mango" data-id="3" src="/Content/Images/FlavourLab/mango.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
         <img data-name="strawberries" alt="strawberries" data-id="4" src="/Content/Images/FlavourLab/strawberries.png">
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
</div>
<div class="boxBtm"></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when one of those images are clicked I need to place the following css circle on top of it to show its been selected the CSS for the circle is like this

```
#circle1 {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
opacity: 0.4;
}

.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Which gets rendered like this:

```
<div class="circle" id="circle"></div>
```

My current jQuery is like this:

```
$("#panel1 row img").click(function () {

   var id = $(this).attr("data-id").val();

   alert(id);

});
```

2 Things:

1. The jQuery does not fire, I'm unsure why. Can someone explain this?
2. How would I add the above CSS Circle to the clicked image?

Comment: Is your jQuery in a document heady call or at the end of the page?

Comment: @j08691 its at the bottom of my page inside the document ready function, did you down vote me?

Comment: Nope. But if I did so what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This `#panel1 row img` is a wrong selector, change it to `#panel1 .row img` - note class name selector `.row`
2. Change your click handler to do this `$(this).toggleClass("circle");`
3. .circle class shall look like:

   `.circle {
         border-radius: 50%;
         border: 2px solid red;
         overflow: visible;
       }`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (the "row" class missed the dot in the selector)

```
$("#panel1 .row img").click(function () {

   $(this).addClass('circle');

});
```